# Manually exposing a CPU Flag to Guest VM for testing purposes

Tags: cpu, qemu, libvirt, cpuid

I have an Ubuntu (trying this on either 14.04 or 16.04) KVM host with an *Intel E5-26xx v3* processor.

There is a certain flag that I need to have exposed to the guest VM, but QEMU/libvirt is not exposing that, even if I use the `cpu mode='host-passthrough'` in my VM libvirt XML definition. I believe this is due to what is defined in this file `/usr/share/libvirt/cpu_map.xml` in which the flag that I like to get exposed is not defined.

So, I'd like to be able to modify `cpu_map.xml` and manually add the CPU flag definition, but I'm not positive on how/where I can get the results of the `CPUID` function and whether they're in `ebx`/`ecx` etc. Any pointer is appreciated.

Disclaimer: I haven't meddled into CPU architecture, so my knowledge is very limited in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the results from the [`CPUID` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CPUID.html) is quite simple:

- Check if the ID flag (bit 21) in the EFLAGS register is set, which indicates the availability of the `CPUID` instruction
- Set the `EAX` and `ECX` registers to certain values
- Call `CPUID`
- Interpret the values of the `EAX`, `EBX`, `ECX`, and `EDX` registers

There are *many* sites convering the interpretation of the results. One of them is [LowLevel](https://www.lowlevel.eu/wiki/CPUID). Many of them only cover a subset of possible results.

[A thread on the specifics of CPUID in VMs](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/468315?start=0&tstart=0) extends this basic knowledge to:

> `UserCPUID` is what will be visible to the guest *Ring-3* code running natively when using binary translation. With binary translation, typically only *Ring-0* (or IOPL-3) code is subject to binary translation.  Most *Ring-3* code runs natively (in a mode we refer to as "direct execution.")
>
> Prior to the introduction of `CPUID` faulting, there was no way to intercept guest execution of the `CPUID` instruction when the guest was running under direct execution. Some CPUs support a limited ability to override the results of some `CPUID` leaves (on a register by register basis) even without intercepting the `CPUID` instruction.  Hence, `userCPUID` is based on `hostCPUID`, but the registers that can be overridden have `guestCPUID` values.

Answer (score 0):

The host-passthrough model will aim to expose every host CPU feature to the guest, but there are some exceptions to this rule.  If the CPU feature is very new, then QEMU, KVM and libvirt may not be aware of its existence. KVM is conservative by default and so will not expose any feature it doesn't know about. In this case, merely editting cpu_map.xml is not going to help as that only tells libvirt about it - you'd still need QEMU & KVM to know about it which requires code changes.  The second case is that some CPU features are not safe to expose to the guest, and so KVM will explicitly block them.

You can see what libvirt believes the host to have by using 'virsh capabilities'